# Problem creating Linked server from local MS SQL to Azure datasource (MS Dynamix 365 CRM) with ActiveDirectoryPassword

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, dynamics-crm, linked-server

When I try to make a linked server from local on-premise MS SQL Server 2019 to MS Dynamic 365 CRM data source, receiving this error:

OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "AZURE" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "AZURE".

```
USE [master]
EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropserver @server=N'AZURE', @droplogins='droplogins'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'AZURE', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSOLEDBSQL', @datasrc=N'XXXXXXXXXX.api.crm4.dynamics.com', @provstr=N'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'
--[SQLNCLI11] MSOLEDBSQL
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'AZURE', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'AZURE', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.com', @rmtpassword = N'XXXXXX
GO
```

When I create a connection as a new Database engine thru SQL Management studio (AZURE using ActiveDirectoryPassword), everything works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you've been reading through [this previous SO answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285640). What version of the [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server) do you have installed on the SQL Server instance?

Comment: I ve downloaded latest driver from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 and same result