# Connecting to Dynamics 365 TDS-enabled database with OLEDB Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, oledb

I want to run SQL Server queries on a Dynamics 365 database.

The administrators of the Dynamics database have enabled "TDS" for me - and now I can easily connect SSMS, using "Azure Active Directory - Password" authentication, and run SQL SELECTs against it. So far, so good!

But I also wish to create a Linked Server to the Dynamics database, and for this I understand that OLEDB is needed? Is that the correct approach?

Hoping so, I downloaded the latest OLEDB provider, MSOLEDBSQL19. My test query, using OLEDB, looks like this:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'msoledbsql19'
    , 'Server={myServer};Database={myDatabase};UID={myUserId};Pwd={myPassword};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;'
    , 'SELECT name FROM dbo.account;'
    ) c;
```

But this results in the following error:

```sql
Failed to authenticate the user 'myUserId' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').
Error code 0xCAA20002; state 10
AADSTS65002: Consent between first party application 'db465503-d247-463e-8a13-95889346b742' and first party resource '00000007-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' must be configured via preauthorization - applications owned and operated by Microsoft must get approval from the API owner before requesting tokens for that API.
```

A search for "AADSTS65002" brings back "*A developer in your tenant may be attempting to reuse an App ID owned by Microsoft. This error prevents them from impersonating a Microsoft application to call other APIs. They must move to another app ID they register in https://portal.azure.com.*"

I have no knowledge of Azure AD and Dynamics, so this is all a little baffling to me - why would trying a Microsoft OLEDB driver be "reusing an App ID"?

Does a change need to be made at my end, in SSMS that is?

Or is the problem with the Azure/Dynamics configuration? If so I would need to pass details of the solution on to the people administering that.

Thanks for any assistance :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's also no problem connecting to Dynamics using .NET code with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, and also no problem with an ADO.NET connection in SSIS.

So it's just the linked server that is still proving impossible...

Comment: Incidentally, trying the method outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829584/problem-creating-linked-server-from-local-ms-sql-to-azure-datasource-ms-dynamix
...I get the same error as the original poster:     
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "AZURE"... It's frustrating that this seems so difficult - has anyone, ever, created a linked server to do this, using standard MS drivers...?